# JBoss push notification to Android

Tags: java, android, jboss, push, mqtt

I have a java application under JBoss and i want to send push notifications to notify the Android device if i needs some particular piece of data, and then the device can send that to the server.

I found two solutions:
 - Android Cloud to Device Messaging (C2DM)
 - MQTT

I'm new to these message protocols and i'm searching if there is compatibility with JBoss. In particular, for the MQTT, i can't find a MQTT broker for JBoss.

Can anyone help me or suggest me other solution for pushing notifications to Android devices?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

C2DM has been deprecated by Google. The current version of the Google Push Service is called Google Cloud Messaging.

On your MQTT broker question: You need an MQTT client on Android and you can use any MQTT broker you like for the server part (for example HiveMQ [1]). The Android client subscribes to the broker and your JBoss application is another client, which simple publishes a message that the client receives. For that to happen your MQTT broker needs to be accessible from Android and the JBoss application, and both need to use the same topic.

As client library for both you can use Eclipse Paho [2] and for testing a public mqtt broker [3].

Hope that helps,
Chris

---

[1] http://www.hivemq.com

[2] http://www.eclipse.org/paho/

[3] http://mqttdashboard.com/dashboard

Comment: Thanks!
My only doubt is if I can develop a point to point model.. because I want to be able to choose which device to forward the message

Comment: If you want point-to-point, MQTT isn't the right tool for the job. To choose which device you want to forward to, you could use a topic namespacing model. E.g. you could design topic names like "app/{clientId}/status"

Comment: Thanks. Yes i think may be useful. Cause i got publish/subscribe and i can emulate point to point with appropriate topics.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [**openmobster**](http://www.openmobster.com/) (Open source Mbaas)

This Provides a mobile platform-independent Cloud-initiated **Push Notification** System.( In Android, the push mechanism is based an a persistent socket connection)

Comment: Thanks!
Does this system belong to "point to point" or to "publish/subscribe" model?

Comment: @TonyLeaf please ask Mr.Sohil Shah ( google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/openmobster-users) for more info!

Comment: Done :) [LINK]https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openmobster-users/EX0XzaXSa5c

Comment: @TonyLeaf Great! openmobster have less documentation otherwise it's a rockstar in  Mbaas world with it's sync features! luckily founder responds quickly!